# Determine if approximate count of features in polygons is less than 100_000

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, point-in-polygon, count

Using PostgreSQL 12.

I have a table of polygons, a table of points, and a table of lines. All tables have GIST indexes on the geometry column. There is a view that includes both the lines and points, `view_points_and_lines`.

There is a script that I run on these that is fairly intensive, and I do not want to run it if there are more than 100_000 total features (points and lines) in the targeted polygons (combined).

Thus, before I run the "intensive query", I would like to determine whether the total count of the features in the targeted polygons is < 100_000. Note that if a feature is included in multiple polygons, it should be counted multiple times.

However, running a query like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(tf.*) FROM view_points_and_lines tf JOIN polygons sf ON ST_Intersects(tf.geom, sf.geom)
```

can be very slow itself, especially if there many polygons and much more than 100_000 points.

I have also tried returning a Boolean like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(tf.*) < 100000 FROM view_points_and_lines tf JOIN polygons sf ON ST_Intersects(tf.geom, sf.geom)
```

but that does not seem to speed up the query, and the query plan is the same.

Given that I really only need a Boolean value, and the count can be approximate, is there any way to speed up this query?

Comment: Have you tried using a different indexing than GiST? E.g. SP-GiST - https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html 4.6.3

Comment: @Encomium I have not! I will give that a try, though it will take a while before I can report back :)

Comment: Cool, curious to hear how it goes. From the docs: "The performance tests reveal that SP-GiST indexes are especially beneficial when there are many overlapping objects, that is, with so-called “spaghetti data”."

Comment: `ON tf.geom && sf.geom and ST_Intersects(tf.geom, sf.geom)`

Comment: @ziggy tried it out - a huge improvement for some of the queries (like >10x!) Thanks! Hopefully in conjunction w/ SP-Gist index it will be even faster

Answer (score 1):

**Update as per comment:**

To count the total amount of intersections with any of of the `polygons`, run a similar *boolean* `COUNT` condition like yours on both tables independently (as per the last paragraph below), and `SUM` them up:

```
SELECT SUM(_cnt) < 100000
FROM   (
    SELECT COUNT(e.*) AS _cnt
    FROM   polygons AS ply
    JOIN   <points> AS e
      ON   ply.geom && e.geom AND ST_Intersects(ply.geom, e.geom)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(e.*) AS _cnt
    FROM   polygons AS ply
    JOIN   <lines> AS e
      ON   ply.geom && e.geom AND ST_Intersects(ply.geom, e.geom)
) q
;
```

---

*Old answer:*

You'd need a `GROUP BY` with accompanying `HAVING` filter to retrieve only those polygons (by `<id>` column) with less than or equal to 100.000 intersecting features

```
SELECT sf.<id>
FROM   view_points_and_lines AS tf
JOIN   polygons AS sf
  ON   ST_Intersects(tf.geom, sf.geom)
GROUP BY
       1
HAVING COUNT(tf.*) <= 100000
;
```

However, it is very likely that the unioned relations (in your *View*) are the key issue here; due to the union of multiple relations, the planner supposedly resolves to using the index on the `polygons` table to gather the intersection counts. Instead, you want each of the implicitly involved joined relations being index scanned.

Try

```
SELECT id
FROM   (
    SELECT ply.<id> AS id
           COUNT(e.*) AS cnt
    FROM   polygons AS ply
    JOIN   <points> AS e
      ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, e.geom)
    GROUP BY
           1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ply.<id> AS id,
           COUNT(e.*) AS cnt
    FROM   polygons AS ply
    JOIN   <lines> AS e
      ON   ST_Intersects(ply.geom, e.geom)
    GROUP BY
           1
) q
GROUP BY
       id
HAVING SUM(cnt) <= 100000
;
```

Comment: hi @geozelot, thanks for the answer! I see now my question was unclear. What I meant to ask about is how to determine if the _total count_ of features over _all polygons_ is < 100_000

Comment: @Avocado oh I see...but it doesn't change much. See my update. Include an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output of your query if that makes no difference.

Comment: @Avocado btw. under certain circumstances (e.g shape of `polygons`), a simple `&&` bbox intersection could be enough of an approximation.